# Make sure content ends up below absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

So, I have a number of buttons that will expand a div with some content below it.
I want to place them in an order so that the expanded content is right after the button that will expand it. This is because I want the tab order to be:

1. tab to a button and click it
2. tab through the expanded content
3. tab to the next button or tab to content below

To achieve this I've made the expanding content to be position absolute. So far so good. The problem now is that the content after the expanded container does not get pushed down.

See page and code here: http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/tab1.html

My first solution to this was to measure the height of the expanded div and add that as padding to a container that is before the content that should be pushed down.

See page and code here: http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/tab2.html

I don't quite like the solution and want something that does not require scripting to get the layout right.

- Can I somehow make the div with class group also "wrap" the container that is positioned absolute?
- Can I somehow position the expanded div in another way that doesn't use position absolute but achieves the same result?
- Or maybe someone has a complete other solution to this case.

Thanks

Comment: is it mandetory to keep position absolute to the div which is getting expanded. if not then use position relative.

Comment: not its not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

you can use position relative to expanded div, ie article in this case.

```
<article id="content1" class="expandarticle">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>

    <a href="test">aa</a>
    <button>bb</button>
    <input type="text">
  </article>
```

your css should be

```
.expandarticle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ccc;
    display: table;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/tab3.html

Did not quite work. Now the remaining buttons get pushed down. I want it to work as in http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/tab2.html but with another solution. Your css does not achieve the same thing I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh Yes!,  this is because the HTML structure we have.  can we alter the sequence of HTML ? if yes then please put all buttons one after another in a sequence you want. and after that put three articles .

Comment: I don't want to do that since that would result in another tab order that I don't want. I've described the order I want in the original post.

Comment: by altering the HTML structure I mean this https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/v6q5pq0p/. please check the jsfiddle. if I am doing anyting wrong in it please update the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you wanted to change but I cant do that cause that will give the wrong taborder.

Hit tab button on your keyboard until you reach a button. Press enter and then hit tab button again. Now I want the first focusable element in the expanded content to gain focus. With your change the next button will get focus which I don't want. https://jsfiddle.net/v6q5pq0p/1/